# Ошибка при рендере

Tags: reactjs

Рендериться по циклу компонент

```
const Recipe = ({ recipe }) => {
return (
<li className="recipes__item">
  <a href={recipe.source_url} className="recipes__link" target="blank">
    <div className="recipes__box">
      <div className="recipes__block">
        <img src={recipe.image_url} alt="recipe" className="recipes__img" />
      </div>

      <div className="recipes__description">
        <h3 className="recipes__title">{recipe.title}</h3>
        <a
          href={recipe.f2f_url}
          className="recipes__link recipes__link--publisher"
          target="blank"
        >
          <h4>{recipe.publisher}</h4>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
);
};
```

И выскакивает вот такая ошибка в консоли. В чем ошибка ?

```
Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Внутри тега `<a>` не может быть другого тега `<a>`, попробуйте второй тег завернуть в `<object>`